# adding unique img src function in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am writing a plugin to check the source of all selected img tags and add the src value to an array , now if a src attribute is repeated i.e if two images have the same src than i don't want the src of the 2nd image to be added to the array , I.E. i don't want duplicate src's .

i have the following snippet or rather function in my Jquery plugin :

```
    function get_prop(current){
        var temp = current.attr('src');
        if ($.inArray(temp , src_storage)) {
            console.log('already in array');    
        }else{
            src_storage.push(temp);             
        }
    }
```

the array is declared in the global scope of the plugin :

```
src_storage = [];
```

now somehow , i did multiple checks and this function seems to be adding nothing at all the the array .

when i simplify the above function code to the following :

```
    function get_prop(current){
        var temp = current.attr('src');
        src_storage.push(temp);
    }
```

all the src's of the selected img's get added to the array , however this gets in the duplicate src's too .

the $.inArray function doesn't seem to function the way i expected it to .

The way i call the function is as follows :

```
$(img).pluginname();
```

so how do i go about fine tuning my function now ?

The entire plugin source code is here , incase u'd like to have a look :

[Source code](http://chopapp.com/#wcrs50nu)

Thanks.

Tenali .

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `.indexOf` directly to check if the value exists in an array. Check the return value for -1 if not found. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

(You can do that with jQuery `$.inArray` too, just check for -1)

Here is an example of the plugin. Passing the array as a parameter to the plug-in. Check that the array now contains only 3 sources, instead of 4 in the example.

***Snippet***:

```js
(function ($) {
    $.fn.extend({                               // defining the plugin
        saveSource: function (arr) {            // the plugin func with argument
            return this.each(function () {      // return all objects for chaining
                var src = this.src;             // get the src attribute of the image
                if (arr.indexOf(src) === -1) {  // check if it exists in given array
                    arr.push(src);              // add it to the end if not exists
                }
            }); 
         } 
    }); 
})(jQuery);

var srcList = [];              // declare the array
$("img").saveSource(srcList);  // call the plugin on all images with the array argument
snippet.log(srcList);          // check the array contents
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<img src="http://placehold.it/32x32" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/32x32" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/31x31" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/33x33" />
```

<sub>* Using a script by TJ Crowder for *console.log to snippet.log*. See here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/230147 and here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069</sub>

Comment: http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js , Is this required ??

Comment: No. I included it only for the snippet. So that you can see the array contents here itself without going to console. For your production code, you only need to use the array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is this line:

```
if ($.inArray(temp , src_storage))
```

Because `$.inArray` emulates the native `Array.prototype.indexOf()` the assessment returns the index of the element if found, or `-1` if it is not. `-1` is still a truthy value; so instead:

```
if ($.inArray(temp , src_storage) === -1)
```

Incidentally, when a JavaScript method doesn't work it's often best to check the documentation, which, in this case, clearly explains what happens:

> The `$.inArray()` method is similar to JavaScript's native `.indexOf()` method in that it returns -1 when it doesn't find a match. If the first element within the array matches value, `$.inArray()` returns 0.

References:

- [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/).

Comment: ! Thank you , quite insightful , i will go through this .

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your line of code:

```
if ($.inArray(temp , src_storage) ) {
```

you should have checked it like below:

```
if ($.inArray(temp , src_storage) != -1 ) {
```

as it returns -1 for not found and 'the array position' for any found array element

Check my test:

http://jsfiddle.net/6g7m345r/