# writing a re usable each function that iterates through all elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i have the following code in my Jquery plugin :

```
    return this.each(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr('src');
        new_src = generate_src();
        $(this).attr('src' , new_src);
    });
```

now i have a function that checks if a particular elements src property is present in an array , if not it adds the current elements src to the array , let me show you that function :

```
  function get_prop(current){
        var current_src = current.attr('src');
        if ($.inArray(current_src , src_storage) === -1) {
            src_storage.push(current_src);
        }
        return src_storage.length;
    }
```

now suppose i do the following in the plugin :

```
return this.each(function(){
        total_images = get_prop($(this)); // this is the new line added , which calls the get_prop function
        $(this).removeAttr('src');
        new_src = generate_src();
        $(this).attr('src' , new_src);
    });
```

notice how i have added the following line :

```
total_images = get_prop($(this));
```

**problem with this approach** :

the each function actually iterates through each element at a time , which means that when i call the below function inside the each function :

```
total_images = get_prop($(this));
```

it will execute only for the current element and than  move on to the next set of elements , WAHT i Actually want it to do is , **ITERATE THROUGH THE ENTIRE SET OF SELECTED ELEMENTS** , return the count and than execute the remaining set of remaining code .

**So what did i do** :

i took the following approach,

```
    this.each(function(){
        total_images = get_prop($(this));
    });


    return this.each(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr('src');
        new_src = generate_src();
        $(this).attr('src' , new_src);
    });

    // function to check for images that maybe repeated .
    function get_prop(current){
        var current_src = current.attr('src');
        if ($.inArray(current_src , src_storage) === -1) {
            src_storage.push(current_src);
        }
        return src_storage.length;
    }
```

notice how i have added the below line of code :

```
this.each(function(){
            total_images = get_prop($(this));
        });
```

now that works just fine , It does what i want it to do , I.E ,

call the get_prop function for all the selected elements . But somehow that seems to be a redundant piece of code , not very neat at all , i am not sure if a seasoned programmer would take this approach , i'am rather new to Jquery , what i'd really like is if i can write a function which inside itself has an each function that iterates through all the elements, but i somehow just don't know how to do it .

Comment: Why does it seem like this question is in continuation to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27687044/1355315 ?

Comment: @abhitalks is this question worth an independent ask ? i feel it is , and so i asked . am i being clear enough in my question , if not , i don't mind editing , also , i do have a solution in mind , which i'll try implementing and if successful share it here as an answer , i am not expecting redy made baked code on stackoverflow , anyways , comeing to my idea , its about writing a function that accepts 2 parameters one , the element to iterate over and two , the function to execute on the elements iterated over , if that sounds vague , wait for a while , till i get the time to post my answer.

Comment: Fair enough. Just wanted a few more clarifications.. (1) Do you want to pass the "generateSource" function as an argument? (2) What are you doing with "total_images"? Your code doesn't seem to use it. Do you want to return a total back from the plug-in to use in the main script?

Comment: Here, I made you one: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/y1ueyecg/

Comment: @abhitalks check out my answer , if u can better it , please post an answer , i'll be more than glad to accept . :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'll try making my answer more clear than my question ,

first of all , WHAT WAS MY PROBLEM :

My problem was with the each function and espically the fact the it iterates over one element at a time. let me show you an example :

```
return this.each(function(){

                $(this).callsomefunction();
                // call some more functions
                // some more set of instructions
        });
```

now looking at the above piece of code , suppose what i actually want is that the each function execute the following line of code :

```
$(this).callsomefunction();
```

for all selected element , before moving to the next set of instructions . now how do i do that ?

@abhitalks provided a fiddle which actually solved my problem : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/y1ueyecg/)

here is my simple version :

i had the following function:

```
function get_prop(current){
            var current_src = current.attr('src');
            if ($.inArray(current_src , src_storage) === -1) {
                src_storage.push(current_src);
            }
            return src_storage;
        }
```

now i want to write a function that when called will execute the above function for all selected elements .

so i wrote the below function :

```
var execute_function = function(element , function_name){
            element.each(function(){
                val = function_name;
            });
            return val;
        }
```

and now finally inside the each function , i have this :

```
return this.each(function(){
                store_val = execute_function($(this) , get_prop($(this)));
                store_val_length = store_val.length;
                $(this).removeAttr('src');
                new_src = generate_src();
                $(this).attr('src' , new_src);           
        });
```

so the code in total looks like this :

```
var execute_function = function(element , function_name){
            element.each(function(){
                val = function_name;
            });
            return val;
        }


        return this.each(function(){

                store_val = execute_function($(this) , get_prop($(this)));
                store_val_length = store_val.length;
                $(this).removeAttr('src');
                new_src = generate_src();
                $(this).attr('src' , new_src);           
        });

        // function to check for images that maybe repeated .
        function get_prop(current){
            var current_src = current.attr('src');
            if ($.inArray(current_src , src_storage) === -1) {
                src_storage.push(current_src);
            }
            return src_storage;
        }
```